# real time update default style in css with custom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any way to add a custom.css file and in this place a rule that takes the margin and padding values in px of the original style.css and divides them in half or change it to 50% or 75% of original? or any method with javascript?

i am trying some as:

style.css

```
.text1{
    padding: 20px;
}
.text2{
    padding: 30px;
}
```

custom.css

```
html.*{ //all element with padding value
    padding: calc(50%);
}
```

html result:

```
<span class="text1">texto</span> //10px 
<span class="text2">texto</span> //15px
```

Comment: You want to do that with a `for` loop on all `elements`. And checking `if (element.style.padding)`.

Comment: if it is not possible to do it with a css rule in custom I imagine it would be with ajax. or jquery ... but this can cause the load to be slow; How would an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Demo 1** is plain JavaScript and **Demo 2** is jQuery. **Demo 1** and **Demo 2** will apply any dynamically adjusted style to every `<span>` but the selector can be anything a CSS selector can be. So if you still intend to select every tag that has padding (wouldn't suggest it, it's very inefficient):

```
"*[style*=padding]"
```

---

Both of them give the same results:

`<span class="text1" style="padding: calc(`**paddingValue**`* 0.5);"></span>`

---

The following is the breakdown of the results:

`<`**selector**`style = "`**propertyName**`: calc(` **propertyValue****valueAdjustment.operator****valueAdjustment.value**`"></`**selector**`>`

---

- **selector:** A String using the same syntax as a CSS selector or jQuery selector.

  - (ex. `<span></span>` = **`"span"`** | ex. `<div id="ID"></div>` = **`"#ID"`**)
- **propertyName:** A String of the CSS property.

  - (ex. **`"padding-top"`**)
- **propertyValue:** A String of the CSS *computed value*

  - (ex. **`"30px"`**)
- **valueAdjustment:** An Object Literal that stores 2 properties.

  - (ex. `var` **`adj`**`= {...}`
- **valueAdjustment.operator:** The first property of **valueAdjustment** is a string of a simple math operator.

  - (ex. `var adj = { o:`**`"+"`, `"-"`, `"*"`, or `"/"`**`}`)
- **valueAdjustment.value:** The second property of **valueAdjustment** is a string of an arbitrary value.

  - (ex. `var adj = { v:`**`"0.5"`**`}`)

    ---

    If using plain JavaScript, do not use shorthand `propertyName`s
    because each browser handles the data from `getComputedStyle()`
    method differently. jQuery does not suffer from this limitation.

    - (ex. `padding` would need to be `padding-top`, `padding-bottom`,
      `padding-right`, `padding-left` if using **Demo 1**)

---

### Demo 1

#### Plain JavaScript

```js
function adjustStyle(selector, propertyName, valueAdjustment) {

  var nodes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));

  nodes.forEach(function(node, idx, nodes) {

    var target = window.getComputedStyle(node, null);

    var propVal = target.getPropertyValue(propertyName);
console.log(propVal);
    var op = valueAdjustment.operator;

    var val = valueAdjustment.value;

    var rule = `${propertyName}: calc(${propVal} ${op} ${val});`;
    
    console.log(rule);

    node.style.cssText += `${rule}`;

  });
}



var adj = {
  operator: '*',
  value: '0.5'
};
adjustStyle('span', 'padding-top', adj);
adjustStyle('span', 'padding-bottom', adj);
adjustStyle('span', 'padding-right', adj);
adjustStyle('span', 'padding-left', adj);
```

```css
span {
  outline: 3px dashed red;
}

.text1 {
  padding: 20px;
}

.text2 {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<span class="text1">text</span>
<span class="text2">text</span>
```

### Demo 2

#### jQuery

```js
function adjustCSS(selector, propertyName, valueAdjustment) {

  $('span').each(function() {
  
    var propVal = $(this).css("padding");
    
    var op = valueAdjustment.operator;
    
    var val = valueAdjustment.value;
    
    $(this).css("padding", `calc(${propVal} ${op} ${val})`);
    
  });
  
}

var adj = {
  operator: '*',
  value: '0.5'
};

adjustCSS('span', 'padding', adj);
```

```css
span {
  outline: 3px dashed red;
}

.text1 {
  padding: 20px;
}

.text2 {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<span class="text1">text</span>
<span class="text2">text</span>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you asked here is an example.

[`getComputedStyle()` is needed, because `elem.style` is only for `Inline-CSS`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

With this example you have the original `padding` value divided by 2.

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('*');

for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  if (window.getComputedStyle(a[i]).getPropertyValue('padding')) {
    a[i].style.padding = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(a[i]).getPropertyValue('padding')) / 2 + 'px';
  }
}

console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.fifty')).getPropertyValue('padding'));
```

```css
div{padding:50px}
p{padding:100px}
```

```html
<div class="fifty"></div>
<p class="hundred"></p>
```